# OpenCVSharp and Unity3d: Internal compiler error

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, compiler-construction, internals

I want to use a Webcam and Blob Detection in Unity3D. 
I read somewhere that OpenCVSharp could be the option, but I have problems adding the dll's.

> Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information.
>   output was:warning CS1685: The predefined type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous.
>   Using definition from `System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'
>   E:\Program\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\System.Core.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
>   C:\Users...\Unity
>   Projects\Game\Assets\Plugins\OpenCVSharp\OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)

Is there a way of fixing this error without taking OpenCVSharp out of Unity3D?